# Or condition with Group By

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables one with observers and another with animals.

Im trying to get the name of observers who have either seen more than 5 animals OR seen a bear.

I am able to get observers with more than 4 animals but not sure how to do the OR statement.

This is my code:

```
SELECT o.last_name, o.first_name, a.observer_id, count (a.observer_id) as Animals_Seen
from animals as a inner join observer as o 
on a.observer_id = o.observer_id
group by a.observer_id, o.last_name, o.first_name
having count (a.observer_id) > 4;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: You don't tell us which column in the Animals table indicates the animal is a bear.  a.observer_id is a foreign key, as it refers to a person in the observer table, according to your JOIN.

Comment: yea I don't think i explained it thoroughly enough. I added an image of my tables to help.

Comment: Sorry I mean 5 or more. I changed it above. Thank you.

Comment: @HansUp agreed on >5 != >4 , but I went with his code sample -- that wasn't the part he was hung up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a boolean value to 1 whenever a bear is spotted... then check whether the observer's bear count > 0:

```
select
    o.last_name, o.first_name, a.observer_id, count(a.observer_id) as Animals_Seen,
    sum(iif(a.animal = "bear", 1, 0)) as BearCount
from 
    animals as a inner join observer as o 
on 
    a.observer_id = o.observer_id
group by 
    a.observer_id, o.last_name, o.first_name
having
    count(a.observer_id) > 4 or sum(iif(a.animal = "bear", 1, 0)) > 0
```

Comment: You get a syntax error from that. (missing operator) in the sum(case when ...)

Comment: I believe Access uses IIF rather than CASE WHEN, I don't have it in front of me to test

Comment: I changed it to: sum( IIF (a.animal = "bear",1, 0)) as BearCount

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to change the logic to show observers who had a count that was >4 for any specific animal (not all animals) and have it show which animals they had seen more than 5 times. This ones a little more complex. Not sure if i should start a new question.

Comment: Yep, new question.  Likely that you'll have to GROUP BY the observer and the animal type

Comment: okay, ill try it on my own first and probably end up back here again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be the WHERE clause

```
SELECT fields
FROM tables
WHERE COUNT(a.observer_id) > 4
OR a.observer_id = bear_id
```

Comment: I think i explained it wrong. The bear is a text attribute within the animals table. I added a picture with my tables and error i get. Also i dont think you can use a COUNT with a where clause. It needs to be a Having clause

Answer (score 0):

Just add the *Or* statement to the having clause

```
SELECT o.last_name, o.first_name, a.observer_id, count (a.observer_id) as Animals_Seen
from animals as a inner join observer as o 
on a.observer_id = o.observer_id
group by a.observer_id, o.last_name, o.first_name
having count (a.observer_id) > 4 OR a.observer_id = 'bear';
```

Comment: HAVING clause can only be used with aggregate functions, the above won't work.

Comment: I think i explained it wrong. The bear is a text attribute within the animals table. I added a picture with my tables and error i get.